# Self-join with distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, distinct, postgresql-9.3

I have this table:

```
   name    code     value
--------------------------
| john  |  0001  |    1   |
| mary  |  0001  |    2   |
| mary  |  0002  |    3   |
```

What I would like to achieve is a result set that looks like this:

```
   name    code     value
--------------------------
| john  |  0001  |    1   |
| john  |  0002  |  NULL  |
| mary  |  0001  |    2   |
| mary  |  0002  |    3   |
```

In other words, I want the result to contain a row with a `code` of `0002` for `john`, which is missing from the table.

I would have thought something like this would have gotten me closer:

```
with x as (select distinct code from t)
select * from t left join x on x.code = t.code
```

but what I get is essentially the same table:

```
   name    code     value    value1
-------------------------- --------
| john  |  0001  |    1   |    1   |
| mary  |  0001  |    2   |    2   |
| mary  |  0002  |    3   |    3   |
```

Some additional thinking brought me to the conclusion that my solution couldn't possibly work anyway, since `name` would probably be `NULL` too, and I really need for it to show up.

I'm stumped, this looks easier than it actually is.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Make it a right join (or exchange x and t on the second line :   `select * from x left joint t on x.code = t.code` )

Comment: @joop I tried before, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also use a `NAMES` derived table, since in your method, which should be opposite of what it is(Either right join or replace t with x) won't return null values for the value.

So you first have to make a derived table containing all possible options of `NAME|CODE` , and then left join it to your original table.

```
SELECT t1.code,t2.name,t.value
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT code FROM t) t1
CROSS JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t) t2
LEFT JOIN t
 ON(t2.name = t.name and t1.code = t.code)
```

Comment: No problem mate :) @s.m.

Comment: one last thing: what if there was also a `date` column that I need from the original table? Would I need another cross join?

Comment: If you want it to do the same logic as the `NAME` and `CODE` , then yea. @s.m.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried adding another cross join selecting distinct dates and added the date on the left join condition, and it looks like it's working :)